# Complex Numbers Problem

Tags: combinatorics, complex-numbers

Find a complex number $z$ such that $z^6=1$ but $z^n \neq 0$ for $n=1,2,3,4,5$. Sketch the location of the $z$ in the complex plane.

This is the problem I am faced with and to be quite honest I have forgotten much of what I used to know about complex numbers. Is this as easy as saying that $z^6 = i^{1/6}$ or is there more to it than that? Such as $z= r(cos\theta +\frac{1}{6}i sin \theta)$. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $z^n\neq 0$? you mean $z^n\neq 1$? surely $z=1$ is required solution if former were the case.

Comment: Since it is asking you to find a graphical representation for your solution, try drawing the complex plane and seeking the sixth roots of unity, i.e. numbers that when multiplied by themselves six times yield the real number 1. What do you know about the graphical meaning of complex multiplication? (**Hint:** they all lie on the unit circle.)

Comment: Also you might want to review your question, since the condition "$z^n \neq 0$ for $n=1,2,3,4,5$" seems to be out of context in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If $z^n=0$ for $n=1,2,3,4$ or $n=5$ then $z^6=z^{6-n}z^n=0$, so the question boils down to solve $z^6=1$. These solutions are the $6^{th}$ [roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity), which explicitly are $z=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{6}k}$ for $k=1,\ldots,6$. You can see them graphically [here](http://plufa10m433.wikidot.com/sixth-roots-of-unity-with-complex-multiplication-usub6).